# Identify invalid query: ExecuteSqlCommand throws: SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: c#, sql-server-2016

I am sporadically receiving a SQL Exception and cannot find any way in which this code would cause an invalid MS SQL statement.

jobsReady is IQueryable< int >

```
if (jobsReady.Count() > 0 && max > 0)
  return this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE TOP(" + max + ") Jobs SET ServerID=" + serverID + ",UpdateTime=@UpdateTime WHERE ServerID IS NULL AND JobID IN ( " + string.Join(", ", jobsReady) + ")",
  new SqlParameter("@UpdateTime", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime, 8, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, 0, 0, "UpdateTime", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, DateTime.Now, "", "", ""));
return 0;
```

sometimes throws:

Error occured in Timer_Elapsed:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: What is the **actual** query that is generated?

Comment: Break the single statement into several lines. Use a local string variable, assign the command string and have detailed look at this string before you call `ExecuteSqlCommand`. You could use the debugger, `Console.WriteLine()`, `MessageBox.Show()` or any logging mechanism. You are sure the variables `max` and `jobsReady` always contains values where no syntax error could be caused?

Comment: good ideas, the max is an int and jobsReady is an IQueryable<int> so always integers

Comment: The responsible way to do this is to create a stored procedure and use proper parameters and a table valued parameter for the `IN` section.

Comment: Store the command into a string variable and you will notice the error, if the issue happens randomly then write all the commands to be executed to a log file and search for the problematic ones.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get an invalid query if jobsReady returns an empty list... I've thrown in random values to the query... see the empty group at the end of the query

```
UPDATE TOP(100) Jobs SET ServerID=100,UpdateTime='2010-01-01' WHERE ServerID IS NULL AND JobID IN ()
```